# What sources are Nico's cool lines taken from?

Tags: nanbaka

In episode 5 of *Nanbaka*, we learn that Nico has a list of cool lines he wants to get to say at some point in his life.

[image: Nanbaka episode 5, 10:48]

Crunchyroll translates these as:

1. This hand of mine is burning red!!
2. Say your prayers, evildoers
3. I won't condone bad guys
4. You're not weak, I'm just too strong
5. Ora, ora, ora, oraa!!
6. The heavens call, the earth cries out, the crowd roars; they are calling me to defeat evil!
7. Balse!

#1 is from *G Gundam* (Domon Kasshu's God Finger); #5 is, of course, from *Jojo's Bizarre Adventure*; #6 is apparently the catchphrase of the title character of *Kamen Rider Stronger*; and #7 is from *Castle in the Sky* (or *Re:Zero*, whichever).

What about #2, #3, and #4? Are they "from" anything in particular, or are they just cool-sounding things Nico wants to say?

Comment: Glad to see newer shows keeping alive the memory of _G Gundam_, my favorite of all the Gundam shows.